# Show/film involving a kid waking up with electrical wall outlets in his hands

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv, horror

I recall watching a show/film in the '90s, in the vein of *Are You Afraid of the Dark?* and *Goosebumps*, where this kid lives in this large white house in the country and wakes up with electrical wall outlets in his hands (some fiendish being is trying to steal his electricity or something like that).

The only thing I've come close  with is an episode of *Are You Afraid of the Dark?*, "The Tale of the Renegade Virus," but I remember it being much different; electricity and lightning were referenced a lot. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. If anyone correctly identifies the show/film you're looking for, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].